# Estado de useState não é atualizado

Tags: react, react-hooks, componentes

Estou desenvolvendo um box de exibição de perfil, onde o usuário pode recolher a visualização ou não. Ele até é recolhido com esperado, mas useState não está mudando o valor booleano para reabrir o componente. Ao inspecionar o elemento, o log informa que o valor do state não muda de false, porém se realmente fosse false deveria retornar a exibição do componente.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como resolver isso?

Segue trechos relevantes:

```
//Trecho de definição do useState

const [isClosed, setIsClosed] = useState(true)

const handleCloseBoxProfile = useCallback(() => {
    setIsClosed(!isClosed)
    console.log(isClosed)

}, [])

// Acionamento da função useCallback
<CloseButton onClick={handleCloseBoxProfile} />
```

Também tentei usar setIsClosed(!!isClosed) porém ai o componente nem renderiza as atualizações.

Answer (score -2):

Realizando alguns testes para buscar a solução encontrei o problema.

O problema está em utilizar a função handleCloseBoxProfile com useCallback, conforme o conteúdo que vou deixar abaixo, o hook memoriza o valor das propriedades para evitar renderização desnecessária, realizando a nova renderização apenas se as props fossem alteradas. Sendo assim basta usar a função sem useCallback, assim:

```
const [isClosed, setIsClosed] = useState(true)

const handleCloseBoxProfile = () => {
    setIsClosed(!isClosed)
    console.log(isClosed)
}
```

// Acionamento da função useCallback

[React useCallback Hook](https://www.w3schools.com/react/react_usecallback.asp)